# How can I show nested objects in single ngx-datatable cell?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

IAttribute:

```
export interface IAttribute {
id: number;
attributeName: string;
attributeValues: IAttributeValue[];
}
```

IAttributeValue:

```
export interface IAttributeValue {
Value: string;
attributeId: number;
Id: number;
}
```

AttributeComponent.ts

```
 export class AttributesComponent implements OnInit {
 attributes = [] as Array<IAttribute>;
 rows = [];
 temp = [];

 columns = [{ prop: 'attributeName', name: "Attribute Name" }, { prop:'attributeValues' 
,name: 'Attribute Values' }];
 @ViewChild(DatatableComponent, { static: false }) table: DatatableComponent;

 ColumnMode = ColumnMode;

 constructor(private productService: ProductService,
          private toastr: ToastrService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.productService.getAttributes().subscribe({
 next: data => {
  this.attributes = data;
  console.log(this.attributes);
  this.rows = this.attributes;
  

  this.temp = [...this.attributes];
  console.log(this.attributes);
},
error: error => {
  this.toastr.error(error.message, "Error loading data");
}
 })
 }


 updateFilter(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

// filter our data
// update the rows
this.rows = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
  return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
});
// Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
this.table.offset = 0;
   }



}
```

Attribute.Component.Html

```
 <div class="card-body custome-datatable">
                <input type='text' class="filter-ngx form-control" 
  placeholder='Type to filter the name column...'
                       (keyup)='updateFilter($event)' />
                <ngx-datatable #table class='bootstrap' 
  [columns]="columns" [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
                               [headerHeight]="50" 
  [footerHeight]="50" rowHeight="auto" [limit]="10" [rows]="rows">



                </ngx-datatable>
            </div>
```

Here is how it's showing me data:

[image]

Here you can see my object:

[image]

Now my question is how can I show only "value" here which is the property of "attributeValue". Like red, green, blue etc. I tried reading ngx-datatable docs but they showed only source code no good explanation there.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options.

1. Use `column template` and format the values as follows :

```
<ngx-datatable
  #myTable
  class="material expandable"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="50"
  [scrollbarV]="true"
  [rows]="rows"
>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="name">
    <ng-template
      let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
      let-row="row"
      ngx-datatable-cell-template
    >
      <strong>{{ row.name }}</strong>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>

  <ngx-datatable-column name="company">
    <ng-template
      let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
      let-row="row"
      ngx-datatable-cell-template
    >
      <strong>{{ formatValue(row.company) }}</strong>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

and in `component.ts` file :

```
  formatValue(values) {
    return values.map((i) => i.name).join(',');
  }
```

2. Format the values first in the constructor and then pass it to the Grid :

```
this.rowToRender = this.rows.map((r) => {
 let formattedVal = r.company.map((k) => k.name).join(',');
 return {
   ...r,
   company: formattedVal,
 };
});
```

Working  [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsovqq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Great! Thank you. It resolved my problem.